# Get the previous jsPlumb instance and create connection to it in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I am using jsPlumb to create a flow chart.

And I add jsPlumb instances(nodes) dynamically on some event.

Whenever I add jsPlumb instancee I want to create a connection of it with the previous added node.

Is there a way to get the id or some useful data of the previously added node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple solution will be having a global variable. Whenever you will add a new node store its id in this variable. and while creating a new node use already added id from this variable. All the best :-)

Comment: I guess voting an answer if its useful is free :-)